# How to compile for a specific `libstdc++` version

Tags: linux, libstdc++

I'm trying to cross compile for an ARM Linux target running with an old OS version. The latest compatible version for `libstdc++` is 3.4.20. How can I compile, using the `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` compiler, specifically for a version less than or equal to 3.4.20 ? Using a Debian-11 based Docker image, the compilation is done using the 3.4.21 version ! Is it possible to compile for an earlier version ?

PS - I'm not able to do changes on the target side.